# vsftpd says : 530 Login incorrect

Tags: centos7, vsftpd, vsftp

i am trying to connect a ftp user

it is showing

```
[root@host etc]# lftp  testuser@:::
Password:
lftp testuser@:::~> ls
ls: Login failed: 530 Login incorrect.
lftp testuser@:::~>
```

and my vsftpd.conf is

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
pam_service_name=ftp
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
userlist_deny=NO
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

please help what is going wrong.

Comment: is testuser in /etc/vsftpd/user_list?

Comment: @aspitzer yes i have added